# Spring Security and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring

I'm creating a spring MVC application using Hibernate and I'm trying to integrate it with Spring Security. So far I have created config files and custom login form.
WebSecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("ADMIN").build());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

And when user goes to admin page ,controller gets data from PosgreSQL data base and puts it in Model. And It did work fine, before I added an /admin URl to a Spring Security for authorization. Now, for some reason I get a java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:490)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCache(SessionFactoryImpl.java:761)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.<init>(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:141)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.<init>(AbstractSessionImpl.java:29)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:248)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1202)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:441)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:456)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:374)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.getAllOrders(Unknown Source)
    com.concrete.controllers.AdminController.getAllOrders(AdminController.java:58)
    com.concrete.controllers.AdminController.showOrders(AdminController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
```

But, if I just remove "/admin" URL from urls which have access restriction it works.
For example, this code runs, and no exception is occurred :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/vip").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

How is Spring Security connected with EntityManager?adminPage.jsp("/admin") which is being mapped by Spring Security uses OrderInfoService from AdminController to get list of entities from DB.
AdminController:

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class AdminController {

    @Qualifier("orderInfoServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    OrderInfoService orderInfoService;

    @Qualifier("JDBCHelper")
    @Autowired
    JDBCHelper jdbcHelper;

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String showOrders(@RequestParam(required = false,value="order")String order, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("orders",getAllOrders(order));
        model.addAttribute("user",getPrincipal());
        return "adminPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin/remove")
    public String removeOrder(@RequestParam int id){
        orderInfoService.deleteOrder(orderInfoService.getOrder(id));
        return "redirect:/admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String adminForm(@RequestParam(required = false,value = "error") String hasError,Model model){
        if(hasError!=null) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Неверное имя пользователя или пароль");
        }
        return "adminForm";
    }

    public Map<OrderInfo,List<ProxyProduct>> getAllOrders(String order){
        Map<OrderInfo,List<ProxyProduct>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        List<OrderInfo> orderInfos = orderInfoService.getAllOrders(order);

        for(OrderInfo orderInfo : orderInfos){
            List<ProxyProduct>proxyProducts = jdbcHelper.getProductsByOrderId(orderInfo.getId());
            map.put(orderInfo,proxyProducts);
        }
        return map;
    }

    private String getPrincipal(){
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you progressed on/solved this? ..sry, I read it only now: The error message + description let assume, that you call `/admin` in/from a "different transaction scope" (what is `JDBCHelper`?/for? ... where your `EntityManagerFactory is closed` ...in `com.concrete.controllers.AdminController.getAllOrders(AdminController.java:58)`;)